# How do I access an array list inside of a class constructor in java?

Tags: java, collections

I constructed a `Purse` class with the following:

```
public Purse(){
    ArrayList<String> coins = new ArrayList();
}
```

My function to add strings to the object:

```
public void addCoin(String coinName){
    coins.add(coinName);
}
```

This idea is that each Purse object can hold a list of strings. I cannot, however, access the `ArrayList<String> coins` with my methods.

For example, this method I wrote to reverse the order of the strings

```
public void reverse(){
    for (int j = coins.size() - 2; j > -1; j--){
        coins.add(coins.get(j));
        coins.remove(j);
}
```

calls the error that the symbol `coins` cannot be found.

How do I make it so that my methods can access the array list I made inside of my constructor? Do I need to say something along the lines of `this.coins.add(coinName)` for the `void addCoin` method or `this.coins.add(this.coins.get(j))` for the reverse method?

Comment: a constructor is a constructor. i have no idea why did you declare your arraylist inside the constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of `coins` outside the constructor:

```
private List<String> coins;
public Purse(){
    coins = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

This would make `coins` a private field of your class, making it accessible from all non-static methods of the `Purse`. Currently, you are creating a local variable `coins` which becomes inaccessible when constructor exits.

Comment: Okay, that worked. Also, I didn't realize that I need to use `this.coins.get()` (or something along those lines). I forgot that I need to clarify which `ArrayList` I'm calling.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `ArrayList` as a field outside of the constructor.  Also use the `List` interface instead of `ArrayList`.

```
public class Purse{

    private List<String> coins= new ArrayList<String>();

    public Purse(){

    }
}
```

When declared inside the constructor the scope of the list is limited to the constructor method.  Declared as a field in the class, the `List` will be accessible by all methods inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the `coins` variable inside of the constructor, you are making the variable local to the constructor block. Once you are outside of the block then the `coins` variable is no longer accessible.

As a result, declare the `coins` as an instance variable of your `Purse` class.

For example:

```
public class Purse {
    private List<String> coins; 
    public Purse() {
        coins = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```